# Regex pattern to get substring of all readable ascii

Tags: c#, regex

I'd want a match pattern to extract all substrings that can  start with either an Ascii or a digit but not with a dash or an underbar.
I've tried this

`string pat =@"^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9]*$";`

But it works for only cases when the string is started with ascii characters and doesn't work for e.g `123something`

Comment: Try the pattern: `^[^\W_][\w-]*$`

Comment: What do you mean by *ascii character*, please? Is it any character with codes in `0..127` range? Or just `A..Za..z` letters?

Comment: `@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+"` starts with `a-z` or `A-Z` or `0-9`; if you want string not only to start from by to contain same character types with - and _: @`"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[A-Za-z0-9_\-]*$"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is *vague*, according to your attempt, I can guess that you are looking for strings which

1. **Must** *start* from `A..Z` or `a..z`, or `0..9`
2. **Can** *contain* any number of `A..Z` or `a..z`, or `0..9`, or `-`, `_` characters

If it's your task then pattern is

```
  string pattern = @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[A-Za-z0-9_\-]*$";
```

If you want to implement `1.` only (the string must start with `A..Z` or `a..z`, or `0..9`, but can contain any characters) then

```
  string pattern = @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+";
```